# SELECT INTO with subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery, common-table-expression, select-into

Regarding SELECT INTO in SQL Server

The following throw an error `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

```
SELECT * INTO Sales.MyTable FROM 
(SELECT TOP(100) * FROM Sales.Customer)
```

The following will pass

```
With tempCust AS
(
SELECT TOP(100) * FROM Sales.Customer
)
SELECT * INTO Sales.MyTable FROM tempCust
```

What is the rule behind that ?

Comment: `SELECT * INTO Sales.MyTable FROM 
(SELECT TOP(100) * FROM Sales.Customer) AS T` You missed the alias of subquery result

Comment: You need to alias your subquery.

Comment: What's wrong with just:

    SELECT TOP(100) * INTO Sales.MyTable FROM Sales.Customer

Comment: Indeed the subquery or CTE is not needed in this case. Initially I wanted to do something that needed a CTE, e.g. Select top 2 rows for each partition partitioned by customerID. Errors occured and I reduce it to a simpler example for debugging.

Answer (score 10):

Can you add an `alias` to your `subquery` like shown below and then give it a try..

```
SELECT * INTO Sales.MyTable FROM 
(SELECT TOP(100) * FROM Sales.Customer) as abc
```

Comment: Spot on. Yet I am not convinced with the 'why'. For self-join (A join A) I can understand. But normally when it's not ambiguous, I tend to skip it and usually there is no problem.

Comment: Besides, regarding [your link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190410(v=sql.105).aspx), why do we need to use join or subqueries. A test with `SELECT StateProvinceID, AddressID
FROM Person.Address
WHERE StateProvinceID = 39` gives me the same result